# A countable process that seems to catch uncountable items

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Here is a rather ambiguous but subtle question I would like to be clarified.

The thing is, I came up with an "algorithm" for finding **all** the equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on a nonempty set $A$ as follows:

- step 1. Take one element, say $a$, away from $A$, and then take all the elements in the rest that are equivalent to $a$. This step gives us the equivalence class of $a$.
- step 2. If for now $A \neq \emptyset$, then go back to step 1 with the current $A$. Otherwise stop.

Now, let $A=\mathbb{R}$ and the equivalence relation be $=$. Then, we should have uncountably many equivalence classes. So, may I ask if I can be sure that the above "algorithm" can still catch all those equivalence classes?

The potential subtlety here that confuses me is that if we follow the **steps** indefinitely, then the process of producing equivalence classes is a **countable** process. So how could we be sure that such process will eventually work for the uncountable cases?

Comment: Your algorithm will only ever generate a countable sequence of real numbers

Comment: I think if you understand Cantor's Diagonal argument for proving the uncountability of the reals, then you could apply that here also to show no matter how many steps you take, you can find an element in $A$ that hasn't been removed yet.

Comment: I agree @WaveX. Saying this algorithm would terminate for $\mathbb{R}$ with $=$ should be equivalent to saying that $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{N}|$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Thank you for your comment, so may I ask if I want to prove something about all the real numbers, I can't use such algorithm as a proper argument, right?

Comment: Typically, inductive type arguments (algorithms etc) are not good for proving things about the reals

Comment: @WaveX great, thanks :)

Comment: If you're interested in analysis I would suggest following the techniques of a book like Baby Rudin or Stein and Shakarchi

Comment: to prove something about all of $\mathbb{R}$ you cannot use the argument you gave here, but you could actually modify it slightly ot make it work. Look up something called transfinite induction. This does however require the axiom of choice to be applied to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The algorithm is not even OK for finding all equivalence classes of $\mathbb N$ under the relation $=$. How do you guarantee that the algorithm eventually selects the equivalence class of $2$? You could select $a=1,$ then $a=3,$ then $a=5,$ etc. and just continue upward forever. The algorithm *does* work if $A$ is a finite set. It also works if every subset of $A$ has a least element and you always require that $a$ be the least element of $A$ that has not yet been removed.

Comment: @DavidK Yes exactly, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @Moosh Thanks, that sounds very interesting, I'll definitely check it out :)